# Gigabyte BRIX GB-BXBT-1900 won't power off

Tags: poweroff

I have just installed Debian jessie onto this machine.  I have had to use lilo to boot it because grub won't work.  Everything seems to be OK otherwise, but when I issue a "poweroff" command, it goes through a normal shutdown routine (ie. everything shuts down cleanly), but it does not power off.  The last two lines on the screen are:

[ OK ] Reached target Shutdown

[1103.745908] System halted

I have tried "acpi=force" and "acpi=off" on the LILO command line, but it does not make any difference.

Any suggestions?

Comment: How about `shutdown -h now`?

Answer (score 1):

Gigabyte support told me to:

"Please disable the standby feature on the unit, please enter bios and under power management make sure that you have ErP set to ENABLE. Try it again with this setup set as Enable."

This worked for me....